# Setting an API Key in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, api-key

I have been working in Python for a short time and know I am trying to use and API that needs a key. I have been given a key consisting in a bunch of numbers and letters. When I search through the internet in order to learn how to "implement" the key I just get opinion and tips but no one talks about how to do it itself. I am using Google Colab.

Could you help me or direct me to some place where it is explained, please?

Comment: What do you need this API for? I assume you are using it in a specific library. If this is the case, it should be specified in the library how to use it. Most likely it will the the input of a function of such library.

Comment: It is an API from an official institution of EEUU goverment and I want to take some statistical data they provide from it. In the documentation it gives instructions for Windows, Mac and Linux users and what they are supposed to do is to writte some lines of code in the operating system, but of course I can not do that in Gcolab.

Comment: Maybe you could write the code in a bash script an then run it from Colab, but this is just a wild guess. Could you provide the link to the docs, so that people here can see the whole problem?

Comment: Sure, here is the link https://pypi.org/project/eiapy/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have the code that you can use directly in Colab:

```
!pip install eiapy
import os
os.environ['EIA_KEY'] = you_API

from eiapy import Series
cal_to_mex = Series('EBA.CISO-CFE.ID.H')
cal_to_mex.last(5)
```

The last 3 lines are taken from the example at [this link](https://pypi.org/project/eiapy/).
I tried it now and it works for me!

Answer (score 1):

By default we don't have OS in Colab. Explicitly mention

```
import os
os.environ[#Your key name] = #API key in " " or ' '
```

I have issue for `OPENAI` Key, example as below:

```
import os
os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] =  "##########################"
```